# Typo3 Extbase Problem: on validation error are values on return empty

Tags: typo3, fluid

I´ve a fluid template on typo3 with a form and the valdiation is in my extension model with annotations e.g.

```
@validate StringLength(minimum=3, maximum=50)
```

if the form has generated an error then extbase show the error on my form. that´s right.
because the inputs on my form are empty after the return.
if i debug the object, this are empty too.

This is my Function in my Controller:

```
public function standardAction() {
}
```

And This my Form in my `standard.html` template:

```
action="standardcreate" name="newStandard" object="{newStandard}" 
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

`{newStandard}` are also empty? Why?

I will give back the values of my form.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, first of all how do you grab the data and validate your model?

The best way to handle that is with two actions, both have a $myModel object as argument, the first displays the form and has a @dontvalidate annotation in the action, the second is for saving the data if validation succeeded. Your form should have the second action as target.

So what Extbase does in this case is: formdata is going to the second action and it tries to validate, validation fails because you provided wrong data, but extbase also sends the action that displays the form internally and will pass back to that action. Because this first action has @donotvalidate annotation it will accept the model with "wrong" values, so you can pass it back to the template.